# Blazor WASM - User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true but unable to get access token without user intervention

Tags: authentication, blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-b2c

I have a dotnet 7 Blazor WASM app, using Azure AD B2C (via `AddMsalAuthentication` in `Program.cs`).

The homepage of the app allows anonymous access, and features a call-to-action to login if the user is not authenticated.

In the layout used by the homepage, I have a dropdown that is populated via an API call.  This will attempt to make the API call if `User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true`.  The API call uses an HTTP client using `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` (which in turn inherits `AuthorizationMessageHandler`) which is responsible for silently obtaining an access token before making the call.

If obtaining an access token fails, `AccessTokenNotAvailableException` is thrown and I call `Redirect()` on the exception, which redirects to the B2C login screen.  This is not the behaviour I want as users are redirected without responding to the call-to-action to log in.

Delving into the library code, this seems to be where Blazor WASM creates the `ClaimsIdentity`.  It calls a JS method in MSAL.js, `AuthenticationService.getUser`:

[image: AuthenticationService.getUser is called by AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory]

If I call the `AuthenticationService.getUser` method in my browser, I can see an object returned:

[image: Result of calling AuthenticationService.getUser]

I note the `exp` claim for the user is a few days ago - in my mind this has expired.

I also notice `ClaimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated` returns `true` when the `AuthenticationType` is non-null.  In my case, the `AuthenticationType` is a Guid matching my B2C app's `ClientId`.

[image: ClaimsPrincipal implementation of IsAuthenticated]

So my question is: what should I be calling, other than `User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true` to determine whether the user is authenticated, and an access token can be provisioned without the user having to re-authenticate?  Should I be using Blazor custom policies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigation, my conclusion is this behaviour is by design.

The default policy out-of-the box simply adds `RequireAuthenticatedUser`:

[image]

This doesn't necessarily do what you'd expect - it adds `DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement`:

[image]

Which in turn simply checks that the Identity is authenticated (which as I noted before just checks for a non-null authentication type):

[image]

My solution was to use a custom policy - in `services.AddAuthorizationCore` - to check the `exp` claim:

```
new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .RequireClaim("email")
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes("bearer")
                .RequireAssertion(ctx =>
                {
                    var exp = ctx.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("exp" , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

                    if (exp is null)
                        return false;

                    var datetime = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(long.Parse(exp.Value));
                    return datetime.UtcDateTime > Clock.Instance.UtcNow;
                });
```